# Values out of ScrollView not get accessed to the Fragment from RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two `buttons` and one `textview` in each child row of Recyclerview. Those two buttons are used as triggers to count number and then write the number in `textview`.

Issue: Text-view value is not Updated while scrolling and the item-count only give the count of items in the list which is visible.

```java
public class RecyclerAdapterItem extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterItem.ItemViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context ctx;

public RecyclerAdapterItem(Context ctx) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public RecyclerAdapterItem.ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewitem_item_tab, parent, false);
    ItemViewHolder holder = new ItemViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerAdapterItem.ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
    holder.Itemname.setText(ItemFragment.itemArrayList.get(position).getItem_name().toString());
    Float  rt=Float.valueOf(ItemFragment.itemArrayList.get(position).getRate());
    holder.Rate.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(rt)));
    holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(ItemFragment.itemArrayList.get(position).getQty()));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ItemFragment.itemArrayList.size();
}

class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected Button btn_plus, btn_minus;
    private TextView Itemname,Rate, qty;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Itemname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Itemname);
        Rate=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Rate);
        qty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Qty);
        btn_plus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        btn_minus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.minus);

        btn_plus.setTag(R.integer.btn_plus_view, itemView);
        btn_minus.setTag(R.integer.btn_minus_view, itemView);
        btn_plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_minus.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    // onClick Listener for view
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == btn_plus.getId()){

            View tempview = (View) btn_plus.getTag(R.integer.btn_plus_view);
            TextView tv = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.Qty);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString()) + 1;
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            ItemFragment.itemArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setQty(String.valueOf(number));

        } else if(v.getId() == btn_minus.getId()) {

            View tempview = (View) btn_minus.getTag( R.integer.btn_minus_view);
            TextView tv = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.Qty);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString()) - 1;
            if(number<0)
                number =0;
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            ItemFragment.itemArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setQty(String.valueOf(number));
        }
    }

}
}
```

This is the `recycleradapter` code.The mentioned `textview` is `qty`.

Comment: Have you checked if "mDataset.get(position).getQty()" is retaining variable qt's value after increment/decrement?

Comment: While scrolling the recyclerview the value of qty  within the view is only retains.All others reset to the intial state.

Comment: You need to move the click listeners for the buttons to the BindViewHolder method and update mDataset item's qty value also.
I will post an answer with the code

Comment: Is there any method for storing the inputted textview values to the array and retrive it in another fragment

Comment: I have changed my code ,please check it and give some solutions

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working then only try this method and try to check update..

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

other wise make interfaces to puls and mins value update like below code ..

```
    onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;

public void setOnItemClickListner(RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}

public interface onItemClickListner {
    void onClick(Item str);//pass your object types.
}
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, final int position)
    {
        Item item=mDataset.get(position);
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        holder.itemid.setText(mDataset.get(position).getItem_id());
        holder.itemname.setText(mDataset.get(position).getItem_name());
        holder.qty.setText(mDataset.get(position).getQty());
        int  rt=Integer.parseInt(mDataset.get(position).getRate().substring(0,mDataset.get(position).getRate().length() - 3));
        holder.rate.setText(formatter.format(rt)+".00");
        ItemDetails listItem = filterList.get(position);
        holder.itemname.setText(listItem.getItem_name());
        holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                data.setPlus(true);
                onItemClickListner.onClick(data);
            }
        });
        holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                data.setMinus(true);
                onItemClickListner.onClick(data);
            }
        });

    }
```

then after define adapter object and bind into recylcer view then call below code ..

```
       recyclerViewAdpater.setOnItemClickListner(new RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(Item str) {
           if (str.getPlus()){
               str.setQty();// set your logic
               recyclerViewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
           if (str.getMinus()){
               str.setQty();// set your logic
               recyclerViewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       }
   });
```

Comment: can you please tell me what you  meant by `data`

Comment: when i used ` notifyDataSetChanged();`  no effect is there.

Comment: sorry it not data pass item object.

Comment: Actually I have no object named  as `Item` , its `ItemDetails `.And my doubt is which object I want  put there instead of `data`.Is it  `item`

Comment: ItemDetails object.

Comment: In interface what ever object define that object pass on click event .

Comment: if interface method pass ItemDetails object then pass ItemDetails object into onclikc method.

Answer (score 0):

Move the click listeners for the buttons to BindView method

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, final int position)
{
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    holder.itemid.setText(mDataset.get(position).getItem_id());
    holder.itemname.setText(mDataset.get(position).getItem_name());
    holder.qty.setText(mDataset.get(position).getQty());
    int  rt=Integer.parseInt(mDataset.get(position).getRate().substring(0,mDataset.get(position).getRate().length() - 3));
    holder.rate.setText(formatter.format(rt)+".00");
    ItemDetails listItem = filterList.get(position);
    holder.itemname.setText(listItem.getItem_name());
    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mDataset.get(position).setQty(mDataset.get(position).getQty() + 1);
            holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset.get(position).getQty()));
        }
    });
    holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mDataset.get(position).getQty()==0)
            {
                holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            }
            else
            {
                mDataset.get(position).setQty(mDataset.get(position).getQty() - 1);
                holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset.get(position).getQty()));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The values in the textview  not resets  while scrolling,but  the values out of the scroll view can't  fetch

Comment: Actually I want to fetch the data to the  fragment.But I can't fetch those values which have the values in qty textview

Comment: You have to save the updated values you print in each textview into mDataset to fetch values out of the scroll view (Actually that's right way to get values visible in the scroll too)

Comment: How can I save the textview values to the mDataset